# Error While executing Google Vision API text detection from file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-vision, keyerror

Hi I am learning Google vision API and I implemented the text detection from file where I have to draw bounding boxes to visualize the words, paragraphs and blocks. But during execution I am getting an error in Pillow library. Can someone help me out? I have mentioned the error below and part of the code down here:

**CODE:**

````
def draw_boxes(image, bounds, color, width=5):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    for bound in bounds:
        draw.line([
            bound.vertices[0].x, bound.vertices[0].y,
            bound.vertices[1].x, bound.vertices[1].y,
            bound.vertices[2].x, bound.vertices[2].y,
            bound.vertices[3].x, bound.vertices[3].y,
            bound.vertices[0].x, bound.vertices[0].y], fill=color, width=width)
    return image```

#CODE ENDS


#Error
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sridhar/PycharmProjects/documentOCR/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 99, in getcolor
    return self.colors[color]
KeyError: (255, 255, 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myOCR.py", line 60, in <module>
    draw_boxes(image, bounds, 'yellow')
  File "myOCR.py", line 37, in draw_boxes
    bound.vertices[0].x, bound.vertices[0].y], fill=color, width=width)
  File "/home/sridhar/PycharmProjects/documentOCR/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 155, in line
    ink = self._getink(fill)[0]
  File "/home/sridhar/PycharmProjects/documentOCR/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 112, in _getink
    ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "/home/sridhar/PycharmProjects/documentOCR/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 109, in getcolor
    self.palette[index + 256] = color[1]
IndexError: bytearray index out of range```


EDIT:
This error happens only to specific images, when I tried with a new image it works perfectly fine.
````

Comment: What is the difference between the images? It looks like you have some key error with self.colors. Does the key exist?

Comment: The error was while drawing a line, I have to draw a polygon to get the error out